# How to stop "canvas.DrawString" from looping? Are there alternatives to DrawString?

Tags: c#

I am creating a snake game for an audiotory rehabiliation. This snake game has an user input (which is the moving snake) and some words (food for the snake). When the snake touches the word (food), the score will add up.

The words (food) are formed randomly using canvas painting imported from my textfile. It consists of 16 lines (2 lines for one question). I already did codes for the randomization part.
Example: a. Hello 
         b. Hey
         a. Hi
         b. Halo

However, the problem right now, is that my "canvas.DrawString" keeps looping and when the snake game begins, the "food" will display all texts from the textfile at once. I wish to only display one word by one word.

```
  string[] x = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\\Users\\TP_baseline\\Desktop\\Level1A.txt");

         string line;
        string line2;    

 private void PbCanvas_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            Graphics canvas = e.Graphics;

            if (!Settings.GameOver)
            {
                //Set colour of snake
                Brush snakeColour;

                //Draw snake
                for (int i = 0; i < Snake.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (i == 0)
                        snakeColour = Brushes.Black;// Draw head
                    else
                        snakeColour = Brushes.Green; //Rest of body

                    //Draw snake
                    canvas.FillEllipse(snakeColour, new Rectangle(Snake[i].x * Settings.Width, Snake[i].y * Settings.Height, Settings.Width, Settings.Height));



                    //Draw food 

                     Random ran = new Random();
                          int check1 = 2 * ran.Next(15);

                    Rectangle rec = new Rectangle(food.x * Settings.Width, food.y * Settings.Height, 70, Settings.Height);
                    Rectangle rec1 = new Rectangle(food1.x * Settings.Width, food1.y * Settings.Height, 70, Settings.Height);
                    FontFamily fam = new FontFamily("Arial");
                    System.Drawing.Font f = new System.Drawing.Font(fam, 10);
                    canvas.FillRectangle(Brushes.LightPink, rec);

                        line = x[check1];
                        line2 = x[check1 + 1];
                        canvas.DrawString("line", f, Brushes.Black, rec);
                        canvas.DrawString("line2", f, Brushes.Black, rec1);



                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: This most certainly has absolutely nothing to do with DrawString but with you loop and its conditions. Before debugging do fix your formatting!